# How to Implement Glassmorphism Effect like in IOS in android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In jetpack compose there's no solid way to achieve Glassmorphic design. Blur View library is there but for it's for the View,

Hack or Way to get achieve Glassmorphic design effect in jetpack compose with piece of code and explaination of it also if possible

Comment: See x3rocode's answer on the linked question.